# error expected '=' ' ' asm or '__ attribute __' before, programa de matrices

Tags: c

Estoy trabajando en Zinjai, estoy haciendo con código que de matrices, el problema es que me manda este error. El código debe de lanzar al final unas filas de columnas, sume las matrices, agreguen un vector y leer un vector en pantalla con sólo números impares.

Todavía no está acabado, apenas es el inicio pero no he podido avanzar por este error **>error expected '=' ' ' asm or '__ attribute __' before**

Entiendo que se debe porque un *{* esta mal puesto, pero después de un rato revisándolo no encuentro nada.

````
#include <math.h>
#define fila 100
#define col 100
int getch()
    int main(void)  {  //AQUI MARCA EL ERROR
    void RestarMatrices(int A[Filas][Col], int B[Filas][Col], int C[Filas][Col], int n, int m)
    void pedir(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
    void mostrar(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
    float mediaAritmetica(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
    float DesvacionEstandar(int [fila][col],float , int ,int );
    int a[fila][col], n=2, m=2;
    float media, desv;
    { int i,j,filas;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        C[i][j]=A[i][j]-B[i][j];
    }
    pedir(a,n,m);
    mostrar(a,n,m);
    media=mediaAritmetica(a,n,m);
    printf("media aritmetica =%f", media);
    desv=DesvacionEstandar(a,media,n,m);
    printf("Desviacion estandar =%f", desv);
    

float DesvacionEstandar(int x[fila][col],float media, int n,int m)
{ int i,j,suma=0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) 
    suma+=pow(x[i][j]-media,2);


return  sqrt(suma/(n*m));   
}






void pedir(int x[fila][col], int n,int m)
{int i,j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) 
{ printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
scanf("%d",&x[i][j]);




void mostrar(int x[fila][col], int n,int m)
{ int i,j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) 
    printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j,x[i][j]);

}

float mediaAritmetica(int x[fila][col], int n,int m)
{ int i,j,suma=0;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) 
    suma+=x[i][j];
    
    return  (float) (suma/n*m); 


}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Nota que te falta un punto y coma tras la declaración de `getch()`

```
int getch()   // <<--- AQUI
    int main(void)  {
```

Por otro lado, por legibilidad suele ser recomendable declarar las funciones **fuera** de otras funciones:

```
// Declaraciones
int getch();
void RestarMatrices(int A[Filas][Col], int B[Filas][Col], int C[Filas][Col], int n, int m)
void pedir(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
void mostrar(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
float mediaAritmetica(int [fila][col], int n,int m);
float DesvacionEstandar(int [fila][col],float , int ,int );

// Implementamos la función main
int main(void)  {
```

Otro error que tienes es que estás confundiendo los nombres de las constantes:

```
// fila y col, en minúsculas y singular
#define fila 100
#define col 100

void RestarMatrices(int A[Filas][Col], int B[Filas][Col], int C[Filas][Col], int n, int m)
//                        ~~~~~  ~~~ 
//                               Con mayúsculas
//                        Con mayúsculas y en plural
```

La declaración de funciones es importante porque el compilador aún no conoce la función, luego necesita información básica acerca de la misma para hacer su trabajo. El compilador no va a tragar con una declaración que no sea válida.

Adicionalmente, en C existe la convención de declarar las constantes definidas con `#define` en mayúsculas:

```
#define FILAS 100
#define COLS 100
```

Esto se hace por varias razones:

- Es más fácil localizar las macros en el código.
- Evitas tratar las macros como variables (no se te va a ocurrir hacer una asignación)
- Si declaras una variable que se llama igual que la macro acabarás teniendo errores de compilación muy extraños. Si ambas se nombran usando minúsculas incrementas las posibilidades de colisión

Adicionalmente, y aunque tampoco sea un error, procura reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible. Declarar todas las variables al inicio de la función es una práctica antediluviana que era necesaria antes del estándar publicado en 1999.

Es, por tanto, preferible hacer esto:

```
void mostrar(int x[fila][col], int n,int m)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) 
            printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j,x[i][j]);
}
```

A esto

```
void mostrar(int x[fila][col], int n,int m)
{ int i,j;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++) 
    printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j,x[i][j]);

}
```

Nota también los arreglos en la tabulación del código.

Otro error que he localizado ... supuestamente está en la función `main`, pero con la pésima tabulación del código es complicado de decir a simple vista:

```
{ int i,j,filas;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    C[i][j]=A[i][j]-B[i][j];
}
```

Este código, posiblemente copiado de otra función, tiene un problema, y es que en la función `main` no existen los arrays `A`, `B` y `C`